# discord.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kickable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, error-handling, typeerror, discord, discord.js

Yesterday I could run this scrip.
Today I get the error

(node:29568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kickable' of undefined

I'm running version "discord.js": 12.1.1 - I hope someone can spot what I'm doing wrong here... because it's drive me nuts.

Bellow you can find my kickuser.js - script
 + my index.js script -> https://pastebin.com/7tLkuU5p

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {

        if (!message.mentions.users) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');

        else {

            const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(696692048543088691);
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            let reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(' ');

            if (member.kickable == false) return message.channel.send("That user cannot be kicked!")

            else {

                if (!reason) reason = (`No reason provided.`);

                await member.send(`You have been kicked from **${message.guild.name}** with the reason: **${reason}**`)
                    .catch(err => message.channel.send(`⚠ Unable to contact **${member}**.`));

                await member.kick(reason);

                const kickEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(member.user.tag, member.user())
                    .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())
                    .setColor("#ee0000")
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .addField("Kicked By", message.author.tag)
                    .addField("Reason", reason);

                await channel.send(kickEmbed);

                console.log(`${message.author.tag} kicked ${member.user.tag} from '${message.guild.name}' with the reason: '${reason}'.`);

            }
        }
    } else {
        message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use kick.");
        return;
    }
}


module.exports.help = {
    name: "kickuser"
}
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`message.mentions.users` always evaluates to true because it is an object, and to check if the message has any mentions, you can do:

```
    if(!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');
```

instead of:

```
    if(!message.mentions.users) ...
```

Comment: Kick user reason (works)

Kick user no reason (works)
but when I don't highlight a user, it fails...
Then I get this:
`(node:7948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: I guess the problem could be in your first if statement, I guess `message.mentions.users` always evaluates to true because it's an object, try `if(!message.mentions.members.first())` instead of `if(!message.mentions.users)`, because if `!message.mentions.members.first()` is another option to check if the message has any mentions

Comment: Thanks 
`if (!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.reply('You must tag 1 user.');` fixed it. Thanks!